# How do I increase the compiz shadow radius above 18?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz

In < 11.10 this can be done from gconf-editor, but that doesn't seem to work in 12.04. The metacity-theme.xml file also set the active shadow much larger than 18, but no effect. So anyone know how?

The shadow radius in CCSM have a maximum size of 18; the shadow can be set to any size below 18. In older ubuntu, it's the same case with CCSM, but shadow size can be set from gconf-editor to a larger number.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured it out myself, for now, but I find **if I put the Y offset up, it gives a nicer look** at least. Sorry I can't answer the question fully; I would love to know, myself.

Comment: Thanks. And sorry too, it seems that we would not find any answer now...

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04.2 cannot change to a higher than 18 value anymore, not even gconf-editor, it just will be ignored sadly.

Comment: Yup, it's kind of make me sad too...